# server certificate verification failed while running ansible playbook to checkout code from gituhub

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible. When I am using a playbook to check out code from github, I got the below error, i have `validate_certs=false` in my `ansible.cfg`.

```
ansible version 2.4.2
platform : ubuntu xenial.

fatal: [127.0.01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin https://github.com/cchurch/ansible-sign.git /root/src/ansible-sign", "msg": "Cloning into '/root/src/ansible-sign'...\nfatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/cchurch/ansible-sign.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none", "rc": 128, "stderr": "Cloning into '/root/src/ansible-sign'...\nfatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/cchurch/ansible-sign.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none\n", "stderr_lines": ["Cloning into '/root/src/ansible-sign'...", "fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/cchurch/ansible-sign.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
===========================================================================
```

`ansible-playbook`:

```
- hosts: all
  connection : local
  become: yes
  become_user : root
  become_method : sudo
  roles:
    - role: cchurch.scm
      scm_type: git
      scm_url: https://github.com/cchurch/ansible-sign.git
      scm_target_path: ~/src/hello-world
      scm_version: master
      scm_notify_on_updated: ansible sign updated
  handlers:
    - name: ansible sign updated
      debug:
        msg: "{{scm_target_path}} was updated from {{scm_url}} to {{scm_update_result.after}}."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is no `validate_certs` option to be used in `ansible.cfg` (at least I don't know any).

Second, the error message that you see comes from `git` executable and not from Ansible itself. To overcome this there's `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` environment variable. You can set environment for every task in the playbook like this:

```
- hosts: all
  environment:
     GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: 'true'
  roles:
    - role: cchurch.scm
      ...
```